# c++. libxml2. < and > are replaced to &lt; and &gt; INSIDE tags

Tags: c++, libxml2

I'm writing a library that creates xml tree from given data.
The problem is that the data contains tags inside nodes.
for example 
`<node> "this is a very <bold>huge</bold> text" </node>` 
quotes - just to separate text given to me=)
When I create an xml using libxml and then write it to console (using xmlDumpMEmeory) I get:
`<node>this is a very &lt;bold&gt;huge&lt;/bold&gt; text</node>`

I understand why it's so but have no ideas how to fix that normally.
The only solution I see is to manually replace < and > in my ::ToString()
But are there any other symbols (like <,>) that I should replace?

Thx for attention

Comment: It's not clear what is consumed and produced by your program. Please put your input and output in backticks, so they get set in a `typewriter font`.

Comment: I understand the situation but not the question. What would you like to see different in the behavior?

Comment: Your data was hard to understand because Stack Overflow treats open and close tags specially.  To embed XML or code literally, you should select the required text and then press the code button (that's the icon `101010`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to embed special characters such as this in the element contents, they need to be wrapped as CDATA.  A conformant XML implementation will always do what you noticed here.

libxml should have some way to write element contents as CDATA that should fix this for you.  [This](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html#xmlTextWriterWriteCDATA) looks promising:

> Function: xmlTextWriterWriteCDATA
>
> Write an xml CDATA.